# How do I redirect to different port on same host in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, ghost-blog

I am integrating [Ghost blog](http://www.ghost.org) which runs on port 2368 into my Meteor application which runs on port 3000. Ghost is a separate instance.

In the below template file, a hyperlink in the Meteor app is pointing to the separate instance Ghost blog.

```
<template name="header">
    <header class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
           <div class="top-nav">
                <div>
                    <a href="{{pathFor 'home'}}">Home</a> -                         
                    <a href="http://localhost:2368">Blog</a> - 
                </div>                                        
           </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</template>
```

It works on my local machine, meaning it correctly redirects to the blogging system. However it didn't work when I deployed to production, as it still pointed to the localhost.

What is the best way to detect the host name regardless it is on local or production? Is there any way to make it work through iron-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Meteor.absoluteUrl([path], [options])` for that (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_absoluteurl).

For instance, HTML:

```
<a href="{{rooturl}}:2368">Blog</a>
```

and JS:

```
Template.header.rooturl = Meteor.absoluteUrl("");
```

Comment: I got localhost:3000/:2368. Do I need to manually take ":3000/" off, like: Template.header.rooturl = Meteor.absoluteUrl("").split(':')[1];? Or is there an easy way? They should support get hostname-only funciton. The second problem is that I always get localhost instead of my real domain even in production.

Comment: In production, depending on how you deploy, you need to manually set the `ROOT_URL` environment variable before starting meteor or your bundle in order to set the right URL. As for changing the result of `absoluteUrl`, yes, I didn't realize the port was included, but that makes sense. You are best of using the url package and just call url.parse on the url you get, and then just take the protocol and hostname from the returned object.